# How to change app name in mac & linuix os desktop flutter application?

Tags: flutter, macos, desktop

I have set my app name in the beginning of the project then wanted to change it after a while in mac & linuix os desktop flutter application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac os:
open Info.plist file inside macos/Runner/Info.plist

then edit product name from

`<key>CFBundleName</key> <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>`

to

`<key>CFBundleName</key> <string>The best project</string>`

[image]

Linuix:
https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/linux

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to do the same in linux ?

Comment: I have add a potential solution that may work in linuix